# Javascript newbie creating objects with ajax

Tags: javascript

I have the following code and want to use it as an object.

How to i access the properties of the object? currently i am always getting undefined!

```
function getLoggerInfo()
{

    $.ajax({
    url: "data.json",
    type: "GET",
    data: {emGetInfo: "logger"},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){
        //alert("1: " + this.loggerName);
        loggerName = response.emGetInfo[0].loggerName;
        protocol = response.emGetInfo[0].protocolVersion;
        $("#console").text("Logger Name: " + loggerName + " - Protocol Version: " + protocol);
        return;
        },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        $("#console").text("ERROR: AJAX errors. " + jqXHR + " : " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
        return;
        },
    statusCode: {
        404: function() {
            $("#console").text("404: The requested JSON file was not found.");
        return;
        }
    }
}); 
}
```

// get loggerName...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   // Get logger info event...
   $("#ajax").click(function() {
    var loggerInfo = new getLoggerInfo();
    alert("Loggername: "+ loggerInfo.loggerName);
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX is asynchronous - so it does not return data ... the following is a (rough) outline of what happens when you use the `$.ajax()` function

1. The data is sent to the url
2. The browser continues - executing other code as required
3. When the url (called in step 1) finishes being processed the `success` callback is executed.

Step 3 could be 1 second, 10 seconds, 5 minutes later

you should process the request in the success callback :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "data.json",
    type: "GET",
    data: {emGetInfo: "logger"},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){
      // process here
      loggerName = response.emGetInfo[0].loggerName;
      alert(loggerName);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your very quick replies, my first time onthis site and its great... the code does alert the correct response but how do i return the value back to the variable that called the script?

Comment: You cant ... thats my point what you can do is execute code within the success callback - you cannot return values

Comment: Doh! thought it was weird how nothing was working! back to normal functions then for this and setup some global vars. thanks for your help, great service.

Comment: Nice, you are now my javascript and stackoverflow guru! :-)